# Realigning Components in AnchorPane in JavaFX 8

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx

I am trying to develop an app using JavaFX 8 and I'm stuck with a resizing problem. The **Selected File** and **Password** fields in the below figure doesn't **realign** as I wish it to be in the **AnchorPane**..i.e. to be in the  **center** with exact distances from the **top navigation bar** and the **footer**. I have tried **AnchorPane Constraints** in **Scene Builder**. I was unable to get a perfect match.

Hoping to get an alternate approach or a small overview of AnchorPane constraints.

**Note:** I'm new to JavaFX graphics library.

Below enclosed are the images and the FXML file that I'm working on.

**What I want is this kind of alignment in full screen mode too.**

[image]

**This is the actuality when I switch to full screen.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick fix, try wrapping your `AnchorPane` in a simple layout, such as an `HBox`, and set the alignment of the `HBox` to `Pos.CENTER`.

However, `AnchorPane` is probably not the best layout pane to use here. You should read through the [layout tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) and figure out a different strategy: probably you want a `BorderPane` as the overall structure with `HBox`s and/or `GridPane`s inside.

Comment: I should have prefer BorderPane over AnchorPane in this case. But can you tell me how to adjust the constraints in BorderPane as we do it in AnchorPane from the SceneBuilder?

Comment: Same way as you do with `AnchorPane`. Just create the `BorderPane`, drop some node into one of it's regions, then with that node selected you will see all the available constraints under "Layout" in the right pane.

Comment: Can you suggest a quick fix whereby I can do it with Anchor Pane only because I have to change a lot of code too...

Comment: I suggested a quick fix in the answer.

Comment: is possible use only  the center of BorderPane?

Comment: Because I need the elements conform to the width of the window, for example....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420202/resizable-page-fxml